i have troubles doing a overlay of a herarchical cluster on a MDS graph in python
enter image description herei have been trying to do a overlay of a herarchical cluster over a MDS graph, so i can have my MDS dots on my graph, where the cluster is marking with a circle the the MDS dots that are similar on a porcenage. i need help with with the codes. and also if you guys know a library to do ecological analisys.
pd1: i have already my MDS graph and also y habe my herarchical cluster by ceparated.
PD2: i leave on this post a example of what i need to do with my analisys.
i have the MDS graph and the herarchical lcuster Graph. and i try to mix it up. i also try to use the library ECOPY but it has problems and it doesnt work.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
